# Get Absolute path of image using ASP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am loading a bunch of images using knockoutjs. I get a json object for each image where the imagePath is relative.
Before using json object I used to bring a list of image in my ViewModel could display the images using template shown below.

```
  <img src="<%=Url.Content(image.PictureUrl)%>" ></img>
```

However now since the images are json I cannot get the PictureUrl defined correctly.

1. I can either get the absolute path in MVC ASP .Net or
2. convert the relative path to absolute in javscript.

Which is better and **HOW DO I DO IT**. I have no idea to this on either ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would almost certainly be to have your MVC application fully-resolve the relative URLs prior to sending them in the JSON object.

In the action method which returns your JSON object, simply call `Url.Content(imagePath)` on each path to resolve the full path prior to sending the response; just as you would were you making the call inside the view.

Comment: that was part of my question as "How Do I do it". I just highlighted the same in the edit.

Comment: @frictionlesspulley Whoops, my mistake. Updated.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Finally figured out what needs to be done. I was getting confused as the previous viewModel displayed all the links using Url.Content on the ASP side.